# Is this a valid way of getting all relational items in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

first of all i'm new to firebase and non-relational databases.
I have spent a couple of days now to try and figure out how to do this efficient.

i have the following data structure in my fb:

```
{
  "Messages" : {
    "-JsG-ltFluSRQvbhY8bh" : {
      "header" : "Message Header One",
      "content" : "Message content",
      "private" : "true"
    },
    "-JsGOTpo-67v8l_3J1wr" : {
      "header" : "Message Header Two",
      "content" : "Message content",
      "private" : "true"
    }
  },
  "publicMessages" : {
    "-JsG-ltFluSRQvbhY8bh" : "true",
    "-JsGOTpo-67v8l_3J1wr" : "true"
  }
}
```

Is this a valid way of getting all items from "Messages" that are set to true in "publicMessages"? OR is there a more effective way of getting them? say there are more than 1000 public Messages.

```
var messagesRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseIO.com/Messages");
var publicMessagesRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseIO.com/publicMessages");

publicMessagesRef.once("value", function(snap) {
    var keys = Object.keys(snap.val());
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        messagesRef.child(key).once("value", function(snapMsg) {
            // assign messages to $scope with $apply
        });
    });
});
```

### /**************** EDIT

I got a good solution on my first question but still i dont understand how i compare two paths
for example: (same as original question but with different paths)

```
"select" all Messages WHERE 

Message exists in users/simplelogin:3/auth_read_messages/

AND Messages/$message/private = true *(maybe this is not necessary)*
```

*WHERE $message is the id for stored messages*

```
{
  "Messages" : {
    "-JsN2eNBAg3jT3D__hCS" : {
      "auth_read" : {
        "simplelogin:2" : "true",
        "simplelogin:3" : "true"
      },
      "name" : "Message 259",
      "private" : true,
      "public" : false
    },
    "-JsNEcngthaVSxhNcmRy" : {
      "auth_read" : {
        "simplelogin:3" : "true"
      },
      "name" : "Message 907",
      "private" : true,
      "public" : false
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "simplelogin:2" : {
      "auth_read_messages" : {
        "-JsN2eNBAg3jT3D__hCS" : true
      },
      "email" : "o@mail.se",
      "name" : "Namn Namnsson"
    },
    "simplelogin:3" : {
      "auth_read_messages" : {
        "-JsNEcngthaVSxhNcmRy" : true,
        "-JsN2eNBAg3jT3D__hCS" : true
      },
      "email" : "s@mail.se",
      "name" : "John Name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set `public` key directly on each message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest and btw. best way to approach it would be to set `public` key directly on each message object. It makes more sense since it is a message object's property.

Then you can search for them like that:

```
ref.orderByChild('public').equalTo('true').on('value', function(snapshot) {
   ...
});
```

You can find more information about this here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: Excellent, exactly what i was looking for. very fast answer.what if i have a similar situation as described above.  but each message is only readable by a list of users, assigned by the creator of the message.? List of users defined in each message AND in each user-account.

Comment: I don't think this is directly possible - firebase doesn't have any equivalent of `OR` or `IN` operator. In that case you could maybe hold the users **lists** in one collection and the reference to certain list in given message object? You'd have to keep a list of lists (yeah…) that user belongs to in the user's object and then iteratively query the messages to collect all the messages that permits access to one of those lists. It would only allow one user's list per message though, so probably not goot enough…